# Typescript setting class variable from contructor via method call

Tags: typescript

Can typescript infer that method called from the constructor sets instance variable.

Typescript compiler complains

"
Property 'variable' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
"

for the code below:

```
class A {

  private variable: string;
  private constructor() {
        this.setVariable("default");
    }

  public setVariable(value: string){
       this.value = value;
  }

}
```

This forces me to  use ts-ignore:

```
// ts-ignore 
  private variable: string;
```

Comment: `private variable: string = '';`

Or

`private variable!: string;`

Comment: No, because there's no guarantee consumers of `class A` will invoke `setVariable`. There's nothing in place enforcing clients of `A` to call `setVariable`. And so reliable inference is not achievable here.

Answer (score 0):

It must be assigned to in the constructor i.e.

```
class A {
  private variable: string; // No error
  private constructor() {
    this.variable = 'default'; // Cause assigned
  }

  public setVariable(value: string){
       this.variable = value;
  }
}
```

Calling a method that initialises it doesn't count.